# relative div inside Bootstrap 3 column gets not respected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a weird behavior for a `relative` div inside a [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) column.
My markup is:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="large" style="background: url(img/bg.jpg);">
        <h1 class="grid-header">Content 1</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.large {
    height: 963px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.grid-header {
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 22px 0 0 22px;
}
```

I don't know why, but the `margin` for `.grid-header` does not working inside `.large`. All margins of it apply to the body, not to its parent element.

Is there anything I don't remember that effects relative layouts inside Bootstrap columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is known as **[margin-collpasing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)**

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

In this case the parent and first-child

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

So you can fix it adding this:

```
.large {
   padding-top:1px;
}
```

Check this [BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/FqKz06F4l0)

Comment: interesting, but that does apply for all browsers down to >= IE 8?

Comment: @supersize you can try I can't at this moment

Comment: no worries, will try it and update when I know. Thanks for your help!